# Efficient concurrent recalculation of a dynamic subset of nodes & their dependencies in a directed acyclic graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I'm dealing with a directed acyclic graph representing calculation steps. Imagine it as something like a big excel spreadsheet, where each cell is a node in the graph.

- A node (cell) can have an arbitrary number of precendents/parents, and an arbitrary number of dependents/child nodes
- The graph is recalculated in cycles, where one cycle should ideally only recalculate as few nodes as needed (see below)
- When a given node is recalculated, its value can either change, or stay the same
- A node must be recalculated in a given cycle if either

  A) the node itself has been externally marked as "dirty" before the calculation cycle started, or

  B) Any of its parent nodes' values changed in the calculation cycle

I'm looking for an algorithm to concurrently recalculate (the necessary parts of the graph) as efficiently as possible. In particular, "efficiently means": Maximize parellelization, minimize recalculating "unnecessary" nodes.

Let's assume calculation is executed on one physical machine with 16 threads, and the graph consists of 10 million nodes.
Data structures can be freely chosen; recalculation should be very fast. Mutations of the graph (adding or removing nodes) should be *reasonably* fast as well.

---

**Example:**

Let's say the graph looks like this:

[image]

A calculation cycle might look as follows:

[image]

At some point before the cycle, A and E were marked dirty.
Cycle starts. A and E must be recalculated during the cycle (marked dirty).
Assume A + E values change. Thereby, D and I must be recalculated.
Assume D + I values change. Thereby, H and K must be recalculated.
Assume I value does change. Thereby, K must be recalculated.
Assume H value does NOT change. Thereby, J does NOT need to be calculated.

Obviously, correct calculation order must be preserved, i.e. even if A+E were both explicitly marked dirty, we need to ensure E is calculated after A.

---

**My two ideas so far**

**First idea:**

Visit every node in the graph. Figure out if the node needs recalculation. Queue up children, if all parents visited.

```
class Node
  number_incoming_edges: int
  value_has_changed: bool


def cycle():
  set processable = New ConcurrentQueue()

  for each root in nodes_without_incoming_edges:
    processable.add(root)

  do in parallel:
    Set node := processable.dequeue()

    if should_recalculate(node):
      node.value_has_changed = node.calculate()
    else
      node.value_has_changed = false

    for each child in node.children():
      if interlocked_decrement(child.number_of_incoming_edges) == 0:
        processable.add(child)


def should_recalculate(node):
  if is_marked_dirty(node):
    return true

  for parents_of(node):
    if node.value_has_changed:
      return true

  return false
```

The downside of this would be that i need to visit (albeit not necessarily recalculate) every single node in the graph, even if just, say, the very last node (by topological index) changed.

**Second idea:**

On graph mutations, I figure out and store the depth of each node, i.e.

[image]

Then do something like (n_depth = 5 in the example above)

```
set dirty_nodes_by_depth = new array[n_depth]
for i = 1 to n_depth
  set dirty_nodes_by_depth[i] = new ConcurrentSet() // will store nodes of depth i that need to be recalculated

for each dirty_node in dirty_nodes:
  dirty_nodes_by_depth[dirty_node.depth].add(dirty_node)

def cycle():
  for i = 1 to n_depth:
    nodes_to_process = dirty_nodes_by_depth[i].to_concurrent_queue()

    do in parallel:
      Set node := nodes_to_process.dequeue()
      node.calculate()
    
      if node.value_has_changed:
        for each child in node.children():
          nodes_to_process[i].Add(child)
```

The upside here is that we only need to visit nodes that actually need to be calculated.

The downside is that we might unnecessarily keep some threads idle.
Imagine a case like below - its well possible that one thread in a given depth is preventing all other threads from moving on to the next depth, even though there are nodes that could, in principle, already be processed.

[image]

---

Given the constraints outlined above, are there any more efficient algorithms to approach this?

Comment: In your example, green color nodes are already processed nodes?

Comment: If so, then you can store info for the nodes at the same depth if they share any descendants or not. If not, then you can simply move to children of a node without waiting for the other nodes to complete that are at the same depth.

Comment: Yes that's right, green is already processed. You're right; I suppose I could combine approaches 1 and 2, i.e. when processing depth N, create a list which nodes of N+1 depend on nodes from N, and allow idle threads to move on to select nodes in N+1 if all dependencies are ready. It feels slightly messy/complex, but maybe that's the best way there is?